# Custom ActiveRecord queries for specific User (e.g Admin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm still new to Ruby and specifically Rails and still learn how to do things properly in a rails way.
So I have `User` class like below

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :email, presence: true, email: true

  has_many :user_program_roles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :programs, through: :user_program_roles
  has_many :user_answers
  has_many :homework_students
  ...
  ...
end
```

From below class, I understand that to get a `program`, `user` has to exist in `user_program_roles`. My question is, is there any way that I can fetch all of the programs without user need to be in `user_program_roles` (e.g. I'm `Admin` and I want to see all of the programs). What's the best way to achieve that in a rails-way?

`Update`

So atm in the app, I can have something like this `current_user.programs` and it will fetch all programs if the `current_user` has record in `user_program_roles`. Can I achieve similar to that, I don't know if I can do something like this in ruby (inside `User` class)

```
def programs
  if admin?
    Program.all # return all program if this user is admin
  else
    programs # return only program that this user has role in it
  end
end
```

Comment: Your declarations are already correct. To get all the programs you simply use `Program.all`. User only exists in `user_program_roles` if user is associated to a program.

Comment: I updated my question, with what I'm trying to achieve. But that code didn't work. Is it possible to overwrite the ActiveRecord method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out what I want. So I ended up using `alias_method`, and put it like

```
alias_method :user_programs, :programs

def programs
  return self.user_programs unless admin?
  Program.all
end
```

I wonder, if there's any side-effect to the ActiveRecord functionality?